# При запуске приложения, вышло сообщение что версия Kotlin 1.5.1 а ожидаемая версия kotlin 1.1.16 как загрузить необходимую версию?

Tags: kotlin

При запуске приложения, вышло сообщение что версия Kotlin 1.5.1
а ожидаемая версия kotlin 1.1.16
как загрузить необходимую версию?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добрый день. При запуске приложения  в Itellige Idea,  в логах показывает  следующую ошибку:  Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.16.